# User appearing twice

Tags: support, users

Look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users). Akhil is appearing twice with two different reputations in 2nd and 3rd positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're two different accounts with different IDs... Looks like he's working from two computers, and accidentally set up two accounts.

Comment: They are merged again now